# OSRM displays any route

Tags: javascript, maps, osrm

API update yesterday OSRM and I'm having problems.

It calls previously used this way:

```
router.project-osrm.org/viaroute&loc=-0.88656,41.68043&output=json&compression=false
```

and it runs smoothly.

Now there is no way to make it work with the new version:

```
router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/-0.88656,41.68043
```

This is the code for the old API, to see if anyone knows how to fix it.

[image: See how it works]

Comment: What's wrong ? what is the error message ?

Comment: No shows the route on the map , that's the problem :(

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information, and other useful information like what you have before, what you obtain, what did you expect, error message, ....

Comment: Edited message with image example

Answer (score 0):

Solved this call: https://router.project-osrm.org/nearest/v1/driving/41.680432,-0.88659841.68

Add https and nearest/v1/driving in URL.